# MySQL counting and sorting rows returned from a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join, count

I have the following MySQL tables with the following fields:

"questions"

```
question_id (PK, AI), author_id (FK), approved ...
```

"users"

```
user_id (PK, AI), username, role ...
```

I want to return the usernames of those who have the most questions and where approved equals 'Y' in descending order but the role must equal '1'.

For example, assuming all users have a role equaling '1', the following data should return the username field for author_id 2, followed by author_id 1.

```
question_id author_id  approved
--------    -----      ----
1           1          Y
2           1          N
3           2          Y
4           2          Y
5           3          N
```

So far, I've got the following:

```
SELECT Q.question_id, Q.author_id, Q.approved, U.role
FROM p1209279x.questions Q
LEFT JOIN p1209279x.users U
ON U.user_id=Q.author_id
WHERE approved='Y' AND role='1';
```

But this returns multiple rows with the same user_id so how do I count the rows for each user_id returned and output their respective usernames?

Comment: You have a db called p1209279x? I find this troubling.

Comment: Move the `role` condition to the `JOIN` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an aggregate function (e.g. `COUNT()` or `SUM()`) in the SELECT list, and add a `GROUP BY` clause to the query, and an `ORDER BY` clause to the query.

```
SELECT U.username
     , COUNT(Q.question_id)
  FROM ...

 GROUP BY Q.author_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(Q.question_id) DESC
```

---

Note that the predicate on the `role` column in the `WHERE` clause of your query negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operation. (With the LEFT JOIN, any rows from Q that don't find a matching row in U, will return NULL for all of the columns in U. Adding a predicate `U.role = '0'` in the `WHERE` clause will cause any rows with a NULL value in U.role to be excluded.

---

This would return distinct values of `username`, along with a "count" of the questions related to that user:

```
SELECT U.username
     , COUNT(Q.question_id)
  FROM p1209279x.questions Q
  JOIN p1209279x.users U
    ON U.user_id=Q.author_id
 WHERE Q.approved='Y'
   AND Q.role='0'
 GROUP BY Q.author_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(Q.question_id) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand your comment regarding the role but should that line read " AND Q.role='0' OR Q.role='1' "?

Comment: @Bhav: It wasn't clear to me. The OP query has `role='0'`, which would exclude rows with `role='1'`. Example data, that demonstrates which "users" rows are to be returned, and which "questions" rows are to be counted. Re-reading the question... I see I missed the requirement to return the rows in descending order by the "count", `ORDER BY COUNT(Q.question_id) DESC`.

Comment: spencer I would recommend adding an ORDER BY in your query to order it by the count desc per the OP request :)

Comment: @spencer7593 Sorry, that was a typo. I only want to count the questions by the users with role=1. I've fixed the sorting by already but thanks. :)

Comment: @Bhav: be careful with the order of precedence between the `AND` and `OR` operators. Entirely possible to include that, but you may want to wrap that in parens, so that the AND and OR operators are evaluated in the order you intend. **`(a AND b) OR c`** is different from **`a AND (b OR c)`**.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add a count to your query:

```
SELECT count(U.user_id) as UserCount, Q.question_id, Q.author_id, Q.approved, U.role
FROM p1209279x.questions Q
LEFT JOIN p1209279x.users U
ON U.user_id=Q.author_id
WHERE approved='Y' AND role='0'
GROUP BY UserCount, Q.question_id, Q.author_id, Q.approved, U.role;
```

But this may still return too many rows, as they may all still be unique.  You'd have to drop some rows out of the select if you want just raw counts.  But that's the basic idea.